# How to configure ServiceStack’s MiniProfiler for SqlServerStorage

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to log ServiceStack's MiniProfiler results to SQL Server like demonstrated here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mknapp/archive/2012/02/22/query-performance-logging-with-miniprofiler.aspx

<sub>Note: The above is not using ServiceStack's MiniProfiler but I found no specific ServiceStack docs on this part.</sub>

My problem is that with ServiceStack's MiniProfiler I cannot resolve '**SqlServerStorage**' like:

```
Profiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(connStr);
```

I have MiniProfiler working in ServiceStack (3.9.55.0 / IIS7 hosted) with ProfiledDbConnection for OrmLite and all is fine with the default on-page/live results (via HttpRuntimeCacheStorage).

Can you see anything wrong with what I am doing below or can you provide a simple example of how to get this running with ServiceStack?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        var connStr = _connStr;

        // *** my problem is that SqlServerStorage is not resolving ***
        Profiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage(connStr);

        // *** whereas HttpRuntimeCacheStorage is resolved and works fine ***
        //Profiler.Settings.Storage = new HttpRuntimeCacheStorage(new TimeSpan(0,0,10);

        Profiler.Start();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Still no luck in solving integrated logging. If case it helps anyone reading this later, you can   log the results explicitly like this: https://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=36

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            MiniProfiler miniProfiler = MiniProfiler.Current;

            MiniProfiler.Stop();

            if (miniProfiler != null)
            {
                Log.Debug(m => m("profiling result id:{0}\nresult:{1}", miniProfiler.Id,miniProfiler.Render()));
            }
        }
```